# Can I just have a color coded HTML editor in Drupal 6 that keeps line indentations?

Tags: 6, wysiwyg

I'm trying to get out some minimally designed pages. The WYSIWYG (CKEditor) has a habit of collapsing the code between saves. WHile this is fine and all, I'm finding myself copying copy and pasting it into sublime text in order to reformat. The copy-pasting -- while not difficult -- is thumbing me up a bit. I've copied/pasted the wrong code and had to redo a lot of my work.

So can I have stop CKEditor from minimizing the HTML code? This is a legacy site in Drupal 6.28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got myself halfway there and without the need to download an additional module, library, or plugin. By checking *Apply source formatting* and *Preformatted*, the Disabled Rich Text rendition shows code indented with some of the white spacing preserved.

You can find these settings in D6 via `admin/settings/wysiwyg`

[image]